# How to automate 'installation process of a software' using Selenium

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, automation, installation

I need to install some software having .exe extension on windows platform using selenium.

Please help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium is a web automation tool, which doesn't interact with system level UI in any way. Full stop.

So this is not about "automating installation process of a software", Selenium has nothing to do with automating with non-web based application in the first place.

You should have a look at [TestStack White](http://docs.teststack.net/white/index.html) which may suit your needs.